# Change programmatically the product layout in Magento 1.7.02

Tags: php, magento, tags

I am using this code in order to create programatically a product in magento

and I have 2 relevant questions about **product tags** and **product page layout**.

```
<?php 

    //$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product'); 
    $product = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Product(); 

    // Build the product 
    $product->setSku('some-sku-value-here'); 
    $product->setAttributeSetId('9');# 9 is for default 
    $product->setTypeId('simple'); 
    $product->setName('Some cool product name'); 
    $product->setCategoryIds(array(42)); # some cat id's, 
    $product->setWebsiteIDs(array(1)); # Website id, 1 is default 
    $product->setDescription('Full description here'); 
    $product->setShortDescription('Short description here'); 
    $product->setPrice(39.99); # Set some price

    //Default Magento attribute 
    $product->setWeight(4.0000); 

    $product->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH); 
    $product->setStatus(1); 
    $product->setTaxClassId(0); # default tax class 
    $product->setStockData(array( 
    'is_in_stock' => 1, 
    'qty' => 99999 
    )); 

    $product->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now')); 

    try { 
    $product->save(); 
    } 
    catch (Exception $ex) { 
    //Handle the error 
    } 

    ?>
```

1) I am trying to also change programmaticaly the product page layout - it should be "1 page layout" always.

**So how do I set programmaticaly the id=page_layout into "1 page layout" ?**

2 ) I know already that I can't add tags to a product.Only the opposite is possible.

**So how to add product ids to a tag relation programmatically?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  this for page layout

```
$product->setPageLayout('one_column');
```

And for tags try this:
Assuming that you already have the tag with the id `$tagId`

```
$productsIds = array(1,4,5,6);//put here your product ids.
$tag = Mage::getModel('tag/tag')->load($tagId);
$tagRelationModel = Mage::getModel('tag/tag_relation');
$tagRelationModel->addRelations($tag, $productIds);
$model->save();//not sure if this line is needed.
```